# How to rotate individual links in a circular chain link

Tags: modeling

I have a circular chain link and I am attempting to figure out how to rotate every other link 90 degrees. I've tried using individual origins and changing orientation to normal, I can't quite figure it out.

[image: Picture of the chain link]

Comment: Transform Pivot Point > Individual Origins, then R and double X (or Y or Z, depending on your links orientation) should work, unless your links are meshes that are part of the same objects, in that case separate them with P (Separate) > By Loose Parts

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize they had to be separated. If you want to put as an answer I will vote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Choose *Transform Pivot Point > Individual Origins*, then <kbd>R</kbd> to rotate and double <kbd>X</kbd> (or <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd>, depending on your links orientation) should work, unless your links are meshes that are part of the same object, in that case separate them with <kbd>P</kbd> *(Separate) > By Loose Parts*, then you can join them again with <kbd>J</kbd>.

Answer (score 7):

...Or, if your links were still an *Array*, you could make that with an *Object Offset*:

[image]

The small link-object-axes are shown at the origin. The larger Empty is translated in X by the link-distance, and rotated around X by 90. Every subsequent element will be rotated with respect to the last, by 90 degrees.

If the chain has a Curve modifier, too, it's sensible to parent both the curve and the empty to the chain, so it all doesn't fall apart when it's moved.

The angle can be adjusted:

[image]

(45 degrees, on the right).

Strictly speaking, this arrangement is a bit lazy. The links are deformed by the curve. One way to avoid that is not to array the links directly. Instead, array a plane, (blue, on the left, below), to mount the links on. Set the plane's 'Object Properties' tab  > 'Relations' > 'Instancing' to instance one link per face. The planes will distort with the curve, but the links will not.

[image]

The plane-array and original link can be hidden.

Comment: yes...but your chains have the wrong color and wrong shape. So i personally would downvote the question but i upvoted it because i like you! ;)

Comment: @Chris Hmmmmm. That way, lies corruption. :) Please try to vote on your independent, genuine view of the quality of a post. Go ahead and downvote if you want to! It helps posters assess how successfully they are communicating.

Comment: The quality of the post is perfect. Just the pictures…

Comment: @Chris you might be interested in this: https://www.amazon.com/Mr-Chain-Plastic-Diameter-10014-25/dp/B07MRD6Y4J and as a safety inspector who trained thousands of riggers - the shape is absolutely correct. :)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady: this chain would make sense with some of the users here ;) :D just kidding ;) and who trained thousands of riggers? you? then train me...i have no clue of rigging ;) ok...just a bit...very little bit

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady: Laskios chain looks like kind of jewelry to me...and Robin made an ordinary chain out of it. You cannot handle art that way! :D :D :D

Comment: @Chris Ok, Ok, Ok.... [1](https://imgur.com/a/f3RxDyz) [2](https://imgur.com/9E0Zh82) [3](https://imgur.com/1P07F7F). Luckily, file still around, so 1 move did it.

Comment: @RobinBetts : AMAZING 